# Kali 3.12 - wlan0 not found

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, kali-linux

I am running Linux Kali 3.12-amd64 on the newest VMWare Workstation on a HP Folio 9470m

My network adapters are as followed:

> Intel (R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
>
> VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMNet 8

When I type 'ifconfig' on Kali I don't get any information on wlan0

Comment: If you need any more information dont hesitate to ask and I will update the post with it

Comment: If Kali is running as a vmware guest, vmware should see your laptop wlan0 device, not Kali.
Kali would see a virtual ethernet adapter (like the one you've shown). This would then be bridged/routed/NAT'ed through the vmware hypervisor possibly through to your wireless adapter and the outside word, depending on how you've set it up in vmware.

Comment: There is no Kali 3.12 version. Its Dec 2015 and the latest Kali version is 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lqueryvg is on the right track:

> If Kali is running as a vmware guest, vmware should see your laptop wlan0 device, not Kali. Kali would see a virtual ethernet adapter (like the one you've shown). This would then be bridged/routed/NAT'ed through the vmware hypervisor possibly through to your wireless adapter and the outside word, depending on how you've set it up in vmware.

However, if you are using Kali, I'm guessing that you are going to want to put your wireless card into monitor mode to use things like airmon-ng, aircrack-ng, kismet, etc. I'm not sure if you can do this successfully through a virtual device.

I know that you *can* do this with a USB wireless dongle that you tell your hypervisor to "attach" directly to the VM (bypassing the host).

You could also just boot your system into a kali live cd.  Then you should have no trouble seeing wlan0 :-) .

Comment: Really helpful answer. Thankyou!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a realtek device then try installing the dkms from apt or compile the source and install it then. It will fix the problem.